# C++/CLI - Creating a copy of an object

Tags: c++-cli

I have a class called "Piece" and an object "Object 1" of this class. I want to create another object "Object 2" which is an exact copy (i.e. it's members have the same values) of "Object 1". How do I do this?

The members are handles so I'm guessing I need to dereference them and then set each of Object 2's members equal to those of Object 1. What is the syntax for this in C++/CLI?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ref class Piece
{
  Type1 ^ member1;
  Type2 ^ member2;
  Type3 ^ member3;
public:
  Piece(Piece ^ other) 
   : member1(other->member1), member2(other->member2), member3(other->member3)
  {
      //other stuff
  }

  //... Other Functions, 
  // constrtuctors, 
  // destructors etc.
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying each of the members (i.e. having it copy all of the members over automatically)?

Comment: No, you have to either initialize all members, like I did, or assign them, `member1 = other->member1;` etc.